# Broken encoding in Excel report from Java

Tags: java, excel, encoding, report, apache-poi

in my application user is able to download an excel report. When user downloads xls using FF then encoding is fine and umlauts are shown correct. If user does the same in IE and Chrome then umlauts in xls are broken.

Excel report is generated in a servlet using Apache POI v3.10.1 and **filled with the same data** every time. But the xls files downloaded in FF and IE (or Chrome) are different.

Any idea why?

BTW, I tried to set encoding in response header

`response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");`

but no success.

**UPD 03.04.** A piece of code from servlet:

`OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
...
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".xls" + "\"");
...
workbook.write(out);`

Comment: In general, the issue appears only in 'Protected View' mode. It looks like IE and Chrome add something to response in order to notify the Excel that the file comes from the Internet.

Comment: Why are you setting a charset on a binary file? Binary files like excel don't have charsets, that's a text-only thing

Comment: @Gagravarr, I agree. But I don't have any other idea about the issue.

Comment: Can you post your servlet code? I wonder if there's a bug in how you're getting the POI output to the browser

Comment: @Gagravarr, pls see above, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

IE somehow cannot understand your `response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");`. Try this instead `response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");`. It works on my IE8 and FF35.